# Load a secure page for API front-end website

Tags: javascript

I'm completing an unfinished project someone else worked on and trying work out how to create a secure page for an API driven front-end.
When a user logs in successfully, a local storage variable is being created that contains user information, including user token and user secret.

I require a secure dashboard page that calls secure API's.

Am I correct in the following approach :

1. When secure page loads, a JS routine is executed which checks local storage for user token. Can this be a simple check for user token existence ?
2. If token present then the secure API's are called using the secret key. The api then returns sensitive data to populate table.

Will this work?

**UPDATE:**
Both server and client will run under https. As data in encrypted, secret token can be stored on client.  Front-End is static html/JS making API calls for sensitive data using secret (only available to authenticated user). None of the user data is hardcoded to F/E but instead is referenced from local storage. Then tokens can be used securely to make further API calls as required for sensitive data. So basically, no-one else should be able to get to sensitive data as cookie/storage is limited to client machine and will expire anyway.
I was looking for a blog/tutorial to confirm my understanding as above.

Thanks

Comment: I'd clarify that when the secure page loads, it's 'loading' whilst using the token is verified on the API end. Then, if the token isn't accepted, redirect to login or something or, if it is accepted then, load the sensitive data.

Comment: Correct, visitor logs in with email/password, then login api verifies with server and returns back to login page, sets the returned data to Local Storage,then redirects to secure page.
@Tony- could you verify approach pls?

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems OK. I don't know your exact requirements, but I would suggest using a cookie instead of localstorage, given that the token is sensitive information and should not be stored for a long time if it doesn't have to.

If the user has it's personal permanent access token go with localstorage. If the token is fetched from an auth-server upon login, use cookies instead.

Comment: i was thinking cookie or session storage myself for the same reason, not sure why previous dev used local storage though. maybe API or vue related ?

Comment: LocalStorage is very often the goto solution because it's quite intuitive. It was probably the easiest solution for him. Do you have an auth server, or is the token on a per-user basis?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by auth server. When user is registered the code creates a User Token in db which never changes. Only the secret key is refreshed when user logs out.

Comment: If you know of any tutorials/templates that demonstrate my situation, it would help a lot. I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: By auth server i mean a server that provisions tokens, when you request one ([JWT](https://jwt.io/), user-sessions...). Given that the secret key changes, use expiring cookies. It should not be hard to swap out the localstorage with cookies.

Comment: I don't have enough information about your situation to give you tutorials or guides. For that, you need to explain the situation further. How are you making the requests?

Comment: When user logs out I presume the local storage is deleted, so unclear why I should be switching local storage to cookies. Could you explain further pls?

Comment: All requests are REST API calls to Express.

Comment: local storage is for longer term persistance. Cookies are temporary, and can have a "timeout" that deletes it after a given time

Comment: I've updated question. Looking for a blog/tutorial to confirm my understanding